# Place WebView in the center of LinearLayout

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have been trying different methods but failing to place the webview in the middle of my `LinearLayout` (or screen)

I am only loading one element in my `WebView` that is a `YouTube Video iFrame`

My Layout is the following which contains the webview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#0c0000"
    android:id="@+id/webviewlayoutVDO">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/loadinglayout"
        android:gravity="center">
        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/theloadingbar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/webviewlayoutVDOInternal">
        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webviewVideo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:gravity="center" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/videoDetails"
        android:gravity="bottom">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/videoText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="PLAY"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:gravity="bottom|center" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

> **The results are the following**

[image: All the blank space]

I want it to be right in the middle instead of loading iframe at the top.

I tried to add some `css` to centre the iframe but I ended up creating a mess.

Is there any way to do this?

Following is my webview code

```
webView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
webView.Settings.LoadWithOverviewMode = true;
webView.Settings.UseWideViewPort = false;
webView.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Black);
webView.LoadDataWithBaseURL("https://.", IFRAME_CONTENT, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> center_vertical : Place object in the vertical center of its container, not changing its size.

Use `android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"`

i.e.

```
<WebView
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:id="@+id/webviewVideo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp" />
```

re: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams

FYI: `fill_parent` is deprecated and thus you should be using `match_parent` unless you are targeting API_1 thru 7.

Comment: simply using `android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"` worked perfectly, thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

change inside your LinearLayout from

```
android:gravity="center"
```

to

```
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
```

Also you can try

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
```

`android:gravity` handles the alignment of its children,

`android:layout_gravity` handles the alignment of itself.

Comment: That was a good answer although i tried both of your solutions and they did not work, i tried `android:gravity="center_horizontal"` and `android:layout_gravity="center"` - SushiHangover's solution worked which was `android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"`

Answer (score 0):

Set the gravity of the layout to centre. 
 
`android:gravity` impacts the children of the layout, while

`android:layout_gravity` impacts the component

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/webviewlayoutVDOInternal">
        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webviewVideo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
             />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to match the width and height of webview like

```
<WebView android:id="@+id/webviewVideo" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_marginLeft="0dp" android:layout_marginRight="0dp" />
```